# flutter why do I need to subtract an object's position from another object's position to find direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am playing around with cubes and making a box aim at a cube in unity, but to use quaternion.LookRotation I need to subtract the long box's position from the cube's position, I don't get why. What if I just use quaternion.LookRotation with the cube's position.

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 directionToFace = cube.position - transform.position;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToFace);
    // Idk why but this line worked too : transform.rotation = Quaternion(directionToFace);
}
```

When I use just the cube's position to aim at, it aims slightly higher but when I subtract it it aims exactly at the cube, and also what's the use of using Quaternion.LookRotation, using just Quaternion works fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cube.position - transform.position` is a direction (actually a verctor .. a direction usually is additionally normalized) from your `transform.position` towards the `cube.position`.

Only using the `cube.position` would rather be a direction from the World's origin `0,0,0` towards the cube.

So in case your `transform.position` is coincidentally currently placed on (or close to) `0,0,0` anyway it might result in (almost) the same direction.

But using `cube.position - transform.position` is correct in a general usage regardless of if your `transform.position` matches exactly the world origin `0,0,0`.

---

Unless you have your own implementation of a method called `Quaternion` taking a `Vector3` as parameter your given code would not even compile with `Quaternion(directionToFace)`.

There is no such method we know about.

Also the [constructor of `Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-ctor.html) does not take a `Vector3`. So it also wouldn't compile if you used `new` like

```
transform.rotation = new Quaternion(directionToFace);
```

Comment: thanks a lottt, that was all I needed, and for the quaternion(directionToFace) I accidentally didn't save it so I was still using Quaternion.LookDirection my bad, appreciate it.